# Identifying an icon that looks like two persons standing in a line

Tags: notification-icons

I found this unknown icon in my status bar. What does it stands for?

[image: image pointing out icon]
[image: without edit]

<sub>Click image(s) for larger version</sub>

Device : Coolpad note 3 running Android Marshmallow

Comment: People, Group, or Account icon... do you have multiple accounts or a guest account enabled? What device and android versions?

Comment: No I don't, I never created any account. I'm using coolpad note 3 running Android marshmallow

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out but thanks everyone for there help. This icon is for meeting mode, somehow I enabled it.